# Выровнять элементы по ширине с flexbox

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Есть 10 элементов шириной 30px нужно с применением флексбокс выровнять их по горизонтали в родителе шириной 200px чтобы получилось по 5 элементов в 2 строки.
Вот пример кода:

```css
.filter__select-color {
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 70px;
}

.color__item {
 max-width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #454a4d;
 flex-basis: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter__select-color">
  <div class="color__item color_black"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_orange"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_blue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_lightblue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_green"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_gray"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_sand"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_white"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_pink"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_beige"></div>
</div>
```

Уже голову сломал над этим. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.filter__select-color {
    width: 200px;
    display:flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.color__item {
    flex:0 0 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #454a4d;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter__select-color">
  <div class="color__item color_black"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_orange"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_blue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_lightblue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_green"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_gray"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_sand"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_white"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_pink"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_beige"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.filter__select-color {
  display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.color__item {
 max-width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
  margin: 0 2px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #454a4d;
 flex-basis: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter__select-color">
  <div class="color__item color_black"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_orange"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_blue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_lightblue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_green"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_gray"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_sand"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_white"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_pink"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_beige"></div>
</div>
```

Еще вариант с маргинами:

```css
.filter__select-color {
  display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 height: 70px;
  width: 200px;
}

.color__item {
 max-width: 30px;
 height: 30px;
 border-radius: 3px;
 background: #454a4d;
 flex-basis: 30px;
 cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.color__item:nth-child(5n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter__select-color">
  <div class="color__item color_black"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_orange"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_blue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_lightblue"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_green"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_gray"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_sand"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_white"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_pink"></div>
  <div class="color__item color_beige"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Из представленных ответов ваш наиболее подходящий, но все равно немного не то. Разве без маргинов обойтись нельзя? У flexbox есть замечательное свойство justify-content: space-between вот на подобии его принципа работы мне и нужна структура чтобы крайние к границам блока элементы (1,5,6,10) оставались без отступов.

Comment: @ConstantineShibaev все верно. `Css свойство justify-content определяет то, как будут выровнены элементы вдоль главной оси.`, `space-between: первый блок располагается в начале главной оси, последний блок – в конце, все остальные блоки равномерно распределены в оставшемся пространстве.` Т.к. ширина блоков `30px`, а блока родителя `200px`, следовательно в одну строку может поместиться 6 блоков `200 / 30 = 6`. Конкретное количество блоков в строке задать, по-моему нельзя. Поэтому без маргинов не обойтись.

Comment: Могу предложить вот такой [вариант](http://codepen.io/slippyk/pen/yVRGNa), если подойдет, исправлю основной ответ.

Comment: Да над этим вариантом я и сам думал, но он зайдет в том случае если ширина блока будет неизменна, а если она будет (width: 100% min-width: 200px) тогда вариант не эффективен.